# How to use 'select ' in MySQL 'insert' statement

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I'm trying to insert additional rows into a table which requires a value to be retrieved from another table. Below is an example query:

```
insert into a.grades (rollno, grade)
values(select rollno from b.students where ssn=12345, 'A');
```

Structure of `b.students` table is `rollno, ssn, name`.

I knew the above query is wrong. Is there a way to retrieve 1 value from other table while inserting a row?

Comment: i tried it without paranthesis around select statement. Now i got it by adding (  ).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO a.grades (rollno, grade)
    SELECT rollno, 'A' FROM b.students WHERE ssn = 12345;
```

Some DBMS would accept the following, with an extra set of parenthesis around the SELECT statement:

```
INSERT INTO a.grades (rollno, grade)
   VALUES((SELECT rollno FROM b.students WHERE ssn = 12345), 'A');
```

Answer (score 4):

Columns in insert into and select must be equal

```
INSERT INTO grades (field1, field2)
  SELECT field1, field2 from students where ssn=12345;
```

Answer (score 2):

Tables from two different databases!

### Database1 - person

### Database2 - order

- Table - per_details
- Table - or_details

Here the insert query used under Database 2!

```
INSERT INTO `or_details`(`per_name`) VALUES ( (SELECT person.per_details.per_name from person.per_details WHERE person.per_details.id=1001) );
```