# I have to insert data with the other table field USING PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

Please Find below query for inserting the data but in `h_id` field, I have to insert another table field `id` all variable value I have to get from `POST` method

```
INSERT INTO m_d_details(h_id, name, h_name, surname, village, resi,
mobile_no)VALUES('SELECT id from head_family ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1', 
'$mname', '$mhname', '$msurname', '$mvillage', '$maddress', '$mno')
```

Comment: First select records from another table, save it into array. Now, loop over this array and insert into respective table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003442/how-to-use-select-in-mysql-insert-statement

Comment: Note that it looks like you are introducing a race condition. You probably want to capture the `last_insert_id` from your previous query instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
INSERT INTO m_d_details 
            (h_id, 
             name, 
             h_name, 
             surname, 
             village, 
             resi, 
             mobile_no) 
SELECT id, 
       '$mname', 
       '$mhname', 
       '$msurname', 
       '$mvillage', 
       '$maddress', 
       '$mno' 
FROM   head_family 
ORDER  BY id DESC 
LIMIT  1
```

Comment: I want just pick h_id from another table because remaining values comes through post method

Answer (score 1):

You can select literals in a query:

```
INSERT INTO m_d_details
(h_id, name, h_name, surname, village, resi, mobile_no)
SELECT      id, '$mname', '$mhname', '$msurname', '$mvillage', '$maddress', '$mno' 
FROM        head_family 
ORDER BY    id DESC LIMIT 1)
```