# MYSQL: Compare Values From Two Different Databases and if Conditions Match, Copy Columns

Tags: mysql

I have two databases: db1, db2 with the exact same columns/formatting.

Table names for db1 and db2 are :  T1 and T2

Im comparing 3 columns from T1 and T2..When all 3 match exactly (date, col2, col3) then I want to COPY col4 and col5 from db2.T2 to db1.T1

I have this so far:

```
   INSERT INTO db1.t1 (col4,col5)

   SELECT db2.t2.col4, db2.t2.col5

   WHERE
      db1.t1.date=db2.t2.date AND
      db1.t1.col2=db2.t2.col2 AND
      db1.t1.col3=db2.t2.col3;
```

I'm getting `'Unknown column' in WHERE Clause error.`

(And Im probably missing a JOIN)

Comment: You can do insert select query. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003442/how-to-use-select-in-mysql-insert-statement

Comment: Im not trying to add a specific VALUE though...Just copy from db2 column to db1 column.

Comment: You can export the value from db1.t1 by condition and then you can import to db2

Comment: Take dump from db1 by condition. This might be use full http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935556/mysql-dump-by-query

Comment: You're missing the FROM clause in the select statement