# Result of sql query inserted to temporary table

Tags: php, sql, join

I have this `sql` query in `php`:-

```
$sql = "SELECT customer.id,order.code,
FROM customer
INNER JOIN order 
ON customer.name = order.name";
```

I'm planning to insert it in temporary table I created how can I do it?

Comment: just encode result into json and stored it to temporary table.

Comment: How sir? @renishkhunt

Comment: @Newboy11 share your temporary table schema ?

Comment: First of all i am not sir. just fetch your result and stored it in $result. then after encode $result using json_encode($result); it return string.

Comment: What do you want to do? Getting data from database, inserting in a temporary table and do some processing might be replaced by simply calling a [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) to do all the work, by providing context parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am supposing you need to store two column avlues `customer.id` and `order.code` in temporary table.

First create temporary table suppose `customer_temp`

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE customer_temp(
    customer_id INTEGER,
    order_code INTEGER 
);
```

Then insert values into temporary table as below:

```
INSERT INTO customer_temp 
    SELECT customer.id,order.code,
FROM customer
INNER JOIN order 
ON customer.name = order.name;
```

Now, fetch the records from the temporary table as:
`Select * from customer_temp`.

Note: temporary table are only available for a session.

Comment: I tried this in PHP but not working. returns empty set.

Answer (score 1):

As temporary table schema was not available. I assumed ,

**Table Name** : `temporary_table_name` ; having

**column** : `id` (auto-increment, primary key), `customer_id`, `order_code`.

Change as per needed.

> With **INSERT ... SELECT**, you can quickly insert many rows into a table
>   from one or many tables.

Use this query (after changing `temporary table name` & `column name` from it.)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO temporary_table_name (customer_id, order_code) 
        SELECT customer.id,order.code,
        FROM customer
        INNER JOIN order 
        ON customer.name = order.name";
```

For more info, click

1. [Insert & Select in one query - Mysql Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)
2. [How to use 'select ' in MySQL 'insert' statement - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003442/how-to-use-select-in-mysql-insert-statement)