# SQL INSERT row based on another row with same column value

Tags: mysql

```
SNO | BOARD        | PLAYER_ID     | SIGN
1   | xyz          | 1             | X
2   | xxx          | 1             | O
```

I have created a similar table for the game tic tac toe and I want to insert row based on another row with the same column value.

For example:

If I send `BOARD = xyz` and `PLAYER_ID = 2` then MySQL should consider `SIGN = O`

I can use `ENUM` to only accept 2 values for the `SIGN` column to accept `X or O` values (Suggest me for better ideas).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use 'select ' in MySQL 'insert' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003442/how-to-use-select-in-mysql-insert-statement)

Comment: @JoshuaR. In the link, you mentioned it will insert the same value from another row. But in my case, it should toggle between `X` and `O`.

Comment: It sounds like you want `UPDATE` rather than `INSERT`.  `INSERT` makes a new row.

Comment: are there unique indexes ?

Comment: @JoshuaR. I don't want it with `UPDATE`. When I am inserting a new row, it should toggle the `sign` column value from the other row `sign` column value.

Comment: Sorry about that @SathvikChinnu, I misunderstood.  You'd like to add a row based on a previous row with the same `BOARD` and `PLAYER_ID`?  You can combine INSERT and IF() as in my answer to produce that effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the `INSERT` syntax here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

their example

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

If you combine that with an `IF` function in the `SET` part of the above `UPDATE`, see:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

e.g.

```
IF(SIGN='X,'O','X')
```

you should be able to toggle pieces for players and games.

You'll also need some way to identify the most recent move.  If `SNO` is intended to be a unique incrementing move identifier, `MAX(SNO)`+1 can be used to increment it when you add rows.