# How to use SELECT MAX inside an INSERT statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max, insert-into

**Short Version:**
How can I get the maximum value of a column and use the result when adding a row with INSERT INTO statement?

**Long Version:**
I have read the question: [How to use 'select ' in MySQL 'insert' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11003442/3499427)  and tried to follow the instructions for its answers. This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO employee (id, name, state, supervisorId) SELECT MAX(id)+1, 'Dan', state, supervisorId FROM employee WHERE name='Chris';
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR: 1062: Duplicate entry '7' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

The reason is that I have another row whose id is 7. Consequently,

```
MAX(id)
```

doesn't return the actual maximum value, but a value equal to id of the row containing 'Chris' which is 6.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Don't do this your idea looks to be prone for **race conditions**.. If two inserts happen at the same time both id's can be the same.. Besides you are reinventing the wheel MySQL has `AUTO_INCREMENT` for this ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html )

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have not much knowledge about mySQL but I think there should exist an exclusive lock mechanism, doesn't it?

Comment: "I have not much knowledge about mySQL but I think there should exist an exclusive lock mechanism, doesn't it" Yes but why should you lock a table that lowers thread concurrency on InnoDB engine? @BarbarosÖzhan i assume InnoDB here because InnoDB is the default table engine in MySQL now for a few years.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland, but I tried running this command "INSERT INTO employee (name, state, supervisorId) SELECT 'Dan', state, supervisorId FROM employee WHERE name='Chris';" but it gave me this error: "ERROR: 1364: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value"

Comment: @RaymondNijland ok, thanks, I'll search for InnoDB next :)

Comment: Can't help you without a table structure @ComputerLover run `SHOW CREATE TABLE employee `

Comment: employee | CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supervisorId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |

Comment: Run `ALTER TABLE employee  MODIFY COLUMN id INT AUTO_INCREMENT` then your INSERT should just work fine.

Comment: ERROR: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AUTO_INCREMENT' at line 1

Comment: I changed it to    `ALTER TABLE employee MODIFY COLUMN id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;` and it worked! Thanks Raymond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by replacing this:

```
MAX(id)+1
```

with this select query:

```
(SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM employee)
```

Here's the complete query:

```
INSERT INTO employee (id, name, state, supervisorId) SELECT (SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM employee), 'Dan', state, supervisorId FROM employee WHERE name='Chris';
```

**Update:**

Although this answer solves the general question about getting the SELECT MAX inside an INSERT query, as @RaymondNijland suggested, it's better to make the most of MySQL auto_increment functionalities. To do so:

1) Make your primary key column, auto incremented:

```
 ALTER TABLE employee MODIFY COLUMN id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

2) Remove the id from your insert query:

```
INSERT INTO employee (name, state, supervisorId) SELECT 'Dan', state, supervisorId FROM employee WHERE name='Chris';
```

Comment: This looks to prone to **race conditions**. What happens if two inserts happen at the same time???

Comment: note that you should use `AUTO_INCREMENT` like i commented this can cause very nasty problems to debug because of a possible **race condition** @ComputerLover

Comment: @ComputerLover Although you can use my answer for getting a MAX inside an insert query, for increasing the id, I strongly recommend learning more about how to make the most of auto_increment as Raymond suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Using manual increment on SQL queries can lead to race conditions. 
You should have the AI (auto increment) constraint when you create your table PK (Primary Key).

```
    CREATE TABLE table_name
    (
    table_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT,
    ....
    );
```

If you absolutely have to use manual increment, use SELECT statement.

Comment: Thanks @rusito23, that's what Raymond and Navid had said. I agree that using auto_increment makes more sense in this case, but I was wondering how I can make that query work, even if it's not an auto increment.